# Cat command adding unintended extra lines

Tags: unix, cat

I used the cat command to concatenate two files. When I do a line count with wc, the output file has more lines than the sum of the input files.

Here is what I have tried:

```
cat file1.data file2.data > joined.data
```

The output of wc is:

```
382200628    382200628  55947683538 file1.data
13641861     13641861   1953636328  file2.data
399077626    399077626  57901319866 joined.data 
794920115    794920115 115802639732 total
```

So the number of bytes is the sum of the two files, but the number of lines is not. I thought cat might interpret some of the content as newline character. However, there are no extra lines if I run cat on the independent files:

```
cat file1.data > file1Cat.data
wc file1.data file1Cat.data
385443054    385443054  55947683538 file1.data
385443054    385443054  55947683538 file1Cat.data
770886108    770886108 111895367076 total

cat file2.data > file2Cat.data
wc file2.data file2Cat.data
13641861   13641861 1953636328 file2.data
13641861   13641861 1953636328 file2Cat.data 
27283722   27283722 3907272656 total
```

The file content are semicolon separated numbers and hex strings. This is one example line:

1559742559;7899594;0x2a65Aca4D5fC5B5C859090a6c34d164135398226;0;0xb75A82e53BCF5E25cFe15B8a014A2bBc34A468C7;0;254905240000000000;1000000000;50000;0;4331209

Any idea why this is happening and how to prevent it?

EDIT:
I split the file in many files of 1000000 lines each. Running wc on the split files, one of them (split_kj) shows less than 1000000 lines. In this file, at a certain point all the information is replaced with zero-bytes. The files following also show less lines, however the information seems to be fine. After copying them, the wc output shows 1000000 lines. For split_kj, the problem still remains. Does this indicate memory corruption?

```
...
1000000     1000000   144774157 split_ki
 455140      455141   145081810 split_kj
      0           0   144771155 split_kk
      0           0   145471556 split_kl
      0           0   144974108 split_km
      0           0   145044520 split_kn
      0           0   144890806 split_ko
 775160      775160   145244231 split_kp
1000000     1000000   144993806 split_kq
...
```

EDIT:
The SSD turned out to have some bad sectors. Thus when the output of cat was stored there, the files were likely damaged. It seems this issue was unrelated to the cat command.

Comment: cat does not (assuming you don't pass any options like "-s" and so on) interpret its input files, so while I can understand a discrepency on one in number lines (can happen if the last line has no newline), I can't explain a discrepency of 3 million lines extra in the joined file. Can you please try again, to verify you didn't perhaps run this on wrong versions of the file, etc.?

Comment: Does `cat -vet file1.data file2.data | grep -c '\015'` return a non-zero number? (just guessing, good luck!)

Comment: running the command you suggested `cat -vet file1.data file2.data | grep -c '\015'`  I get the following output:                                                                                               
`12888300`

Comment: Could be your original file1.data does not contain what you think it does. The blocks of zeros may already be in it. Maybe the conversion to CSV (if there is one) is the culprit.

Comment: Given the 'edit', it appears that the problem is resolved, and was not resolvable by anyone without access to the machine where there was a problem.  This question should be closed and deleted, IMNSHO.  It provides no benefit to SO in the short term, nor in the medium term or long term.